# Touch log file with Ansible only when it does not start with __

Tags: ansible

Using `Ansible 2.7.13`, I'm trying to perform a touch of logfiles in a list only if the filename does start with `__`. I cannot seem to get it running.

Here's my code:

```
# file touch.yml
- name: Touch
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: touch
    mode: '0777'
  when: not (item | basename | regex_search("^__"))
  with_items:
    - "{{ touch_files }}"
```

I call this with

```
touch_files:
        - "{{ path }}/job_count.json"
        - "{{ path }}/query_time.json"
        - "{{ path }}/disk_usage.json"
        - "{{ path }}/__revert__"
```

Which results in :

```sh
ERROR! 'when' is not a valid attribute for a Play[0m
The error appears to have been in '... /playbooks/touch.yaml': line 3, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

Expected result: files listed in the `touch_files` list are touched. The __revert__ file is not touched.

What could be the problem here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your playbook is not valid. You only listed a single task which should be part of a play. Please read the [ansible documentation on playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html) and insert your task in a valid play inside your playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Perform a touch of logfiles in a list only if the filename does start with __ "*

A: There are problems in the code

- `when` shall be used outside the `loop`
- `touch_files` is a list; loop list of lists can't work
- `when` condition is wrong

Try the task below

```
- name: Touch
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: touch
    mode: '0777'
  loop: "{{ touch_files }}"
  when: "item|basename is regex('^__(.*)$')"
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that you haven't wrapped your task in a [play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics). You need to specify the hosts that the tasks will run on and other optional settings.

`loop` is preferred to `with_items` now. You were also passing it a list of lists.

Example playbook containing the task:

```
- hosts: <the-hosts-you-want-to-run-the-playbook-on>
  tasks:
    - name: Touch
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: touch
        mode: '0777'
      when: item | basename is startedwith '__'
      loop: "{{ touch_files }}"
```

I created the custom test `startedwith` to make it a bit more readable:

```py
from ansible.errors import AnsibleFilterError

class TestModule(object):
  def tests(self):
    return {
      'startedwith': self.startedwith,
    }

  def startedwith(self, text, starts):
    if not isinstance(text, basestring):
      raise AnsibleFilterError(
        'Argument to `startedwith` expected to be a string'
      )
    return text.startswith(starts)
```

There's lots of places you can put it but probably the most appropriate is in a `test_plugins` directory in the same directory as your playbook. Call the file `startedwith.py` or whatever you like.

See the [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) for more.